# puppet how to manage service with only if

Tags: service, puppet, configurationmanager

Can some one help me with puppet, I want to launch my service using smt like:

```
service {"my_service":
    ensure     => running,
    enable     => true,
    hasstatus  => true,
    hasrestart => true,
}
```

but It require some some folder that can appear at any time and I can't control it. So I want some thing like `onlyif =>` for `service`

seems that if my service require some `exec` with `onlyif` it's does not work...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use 'require' an exec that checks the existence of the folder?

```
service {"my_service":
    ensure     => running,
    enable     => true,
    hasstatus  => true,
    hasrestart => true,
    require => Exec['checkForDir'],
}

exec {'checkForDir':
    command => "/bin/bash -e if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then; exit 0; fi;",
    returns => '0', #error will be thrown if the command doesn't return zero
}
```

Might need to play around to get the inline command syntax working but that should do it.

Comment: you sure that it will prevert execution of service statement?

if in exec defined `returns => '0'` and `command` execution will exit with other code that will block service?